# Присваивание строки указателю

Tags: c

Совершенно не могу понять одну деталь:

```
char *pName = "Ekaterina";
pName = "Vasiliy";
```

Объясните, как это работает?

Например, почему этот указатель может принять СТРОКУ и поменять ее значение, а потом ещё и вывести целую строку без оператора разыменовывания. Просто могу вывести строку написав: `puts(pName)`. Совершенно не могу понять, как это работает.

Comment: Что значит "указатель может принять строку'? Откуда здесь взялось слово "принять"? Указатель *указывает* на строку, а не "принимает" строку. Потому он и называется *указателем*.

Comment: Вопрос неправильно задал, хотя это уже неважно, на меил.ру подробно объяснили

Comment: @НиколайНиколаевич опубликуйте тогда ответом, чтоб и другим помогло.

Comment: Строковые константные литералы располагаются в специальной секции `.ro.data` компоновщиком. При запуске программы эта секция размещается по определённому адресу. Соответственно каждый литерал имеет адрес начала строки. Вот этот адрес и присваивается переменной, что делает её *указателем на адрес*.